# A question using complex numbers to do trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I have equation $\cos(a)+\cos(a+b)$ and I would like to isolate the $\cos(a)$ part. I couldn't find a way to do it with trigonometry but I found I can do that using complex numbers, simplify it and take the real part of the result. And the process looks like this:

$$\cos(a)+\cos(a+b)=e^{ia}+e^{i(a+b)}=e^{ia}+e^{ia}e^{ib}=e^{ia}(1+e^{ib})$$
Take the real part, I got
$$\cos(a)(1+\cos(b))=\cos(a)+\cos(a)\cos(b)$$

This is wrong because $\cos(a+b)$ obviously not equal to $\cos(a)\cos(b)$. Could someone point out where is wrong and how I can get $\cos(a)$ out properly? Thanks!

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Comment: Use trig identity I always got a sin(a)sin(b) part which doesn't contain a cos(a)

Comment: Your answer is not correct because $Re(xy)\neq Re(x)\cdot Re(y)$ for complex $x,y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was given by @Clayton: the real part of the product is not the product of the real parts.

I want to add that you cannot pull a $\cos a$ factor out of the expression.

For example, with $b=\dfrac\pi2$,

$$\cos a+\cos\left(a+\frac\pi2\right)=\cos a-\sin a=\cos a(1-\tan a),$$ which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Start with
$$\cos(a) = \dfrac {e^{ia} +e^{-ia}}{2} $$
$$\cos(a+b) = \dfrac{e^{i(a+b)}+e^{-i(a+b)}}{2}$$
and also note
$$\sin(a) = \dfrac {e^{ia} -e^{-ia}}{2i} $$
$$e^{ia} = \cos(a) +i\sin(a) $$

From those, you could do the algebra to get a new trigonometric expression.

Although, IIRC,

$$\cos(a+b) =\cos(a)\cos(b) - \sin(a)\sin(b) $$

so

$$\cos(a+b) = \cos(a)[\cos(b) -\tan(a)\sin(b)]$$